# How to extract random subgraph with fixed number of nodes using python networkx?

Tags: python, random, subgraph

I have a large graph consisting of ~80k nodes and ~2M nodes ([SNAP twitter graph](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ego-Twitter.html)). I want to downsample the graph with n number of nodes picked uniformly randomly (n=~1k), without losing certain properties of the graph (average clustering coefficient and average degree).

I can subgraph in networkx using:

```
sg = g.subgraph(list_of_nodes)
```

Is it possible to use networkx to do what I mentioned?